# Error Php shorten text function, need correction

Tags: php

I'm not sure where I'm missing.

I've try looking at the syntax and also the miss spelling function name

but it seems I can't find that problems

the problem is come from line 4 coding

```
<?php

    function shortenText($text, $maxlength=70, $appendix = "..."){
        $text = strip_tags($text);
        if(mb_strlen($text) <= $maxlength){return $text;} 
        $text = mb_substr($text, 0, $maxlength - mb_strlen($appendix));
        $text =. $appendix;
        return $text;
    }

}
```

Comment: What is the input and what do you expect the output to be?

Comment: it should be `.=` not `=.`

Comment: I use this function to shorten the text

if the input texts are too long, it should output "..." at the of the texts

example: 

understanding english grammar -> understanding eng...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You closed twice the function and you have put =. instead of .=
Use an IDE, it underline errors...

```
function shortenText($text, $maxlength=70, $appendix = "...") {
    $text = strip_tags($text);
    if(mb_strlen($text) <= $maxlength){return $text;} 
    $text = mb_substr($text, 0, $maxlength - mb_strlen($appendix));
    $text .= $appendix;
    return $text;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

fourth line must be :
$text.= $appendix;

edit: just saw comment.I guess it was before I could complete my post.

Comment: There is another after that, I closed twice the function. Thank you though

Answer (score 0):

You should change the line like this `$text .= $appendix;`

You should read the [String Operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php)